# How to use the mouse to scroll up/down in MacOS Yosemite Terminal when vi is open

Tags: terminal, osx-yosemite, vi, scroll-wheel

In MacOS X, pre-Yosemite versions I could open `vi` in the Terminal window and scroll up and down the history of the Terminal. The `vi` lines in this case did not scroll.

To scroll I used the mouse-pad's [two fingers](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/20/mac-multi-touch-gestures/) up/down method.

In Yosemite this doesn't work. When I try to scroll up/down, the cursor in `vi` moves while the lines of `vi` scroll up/down.

How can I scroll up the window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior is configurable in Terminal.app, but the default binding for scrolling has changed so that the <kbd>shift</kbd> modifier is no longer need.  (You can change it back, in Terminal's *Preferences*).  Here are some links discussing the changes

- [How to turn off mouse (or touchpad) scrolling when running vim in an xterm?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6699311)
- [Easy Mac Hacks: What's New in Terminal in Yosemite](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/easy_mac_hacks_whats_new_terminal_yosemite)
- [Yosemite introduces per-line scrolling in the Terminal](http://www.macissues.com/2014/06/10/yosemite-introduces-per-line-scrolling-in-the-terminal/)

There are other changes (to <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd>) introduced in Yosemite, which are reflected in ncurses' terminal entry for [`nsterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-nsterm), which is the recommended setting for `TERM`:

- [OSX 10.10](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src-entries.html#tic-nsterm-build343)
- [OSX 10.9](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src-entries.html#tic-nsterm-build326)

Answer (score 6):

In Terminal select Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Keyboard -> Scroll Alternate screen (unchecked) to reset the behavior

Answer (score 4):

In Yosemite vs. previous OSX versions, the scrolling is now done by holding down the shift key while scrolling up\down.

Scrolling up\down without holding the shift key, will scroll through VI's lines.